# First character in a dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So my problem is that I need to create a simple python program that takes an input of 6 characters from the user as a postal code and takes the first character and matches it to the corresponding province. For example: Alberta postal codes start with a T so i started off my program with:

```
pCode = {"Alberta": "T"}
a = input("Enter a 6 character postal code: ")
```

just to start off the dictionary and get an input. The instructions are also that **I must not use loops, lists or if statements**. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: We are not here to help you to win your competition.

Comment: Have you tried `dict.get()` I can't even see that working though if you can only enter 6 characters

Comment: you could `pCode = {'T': 'Alberta'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dict is the wrong way round. The thing you want to look up (key) goes first in each pair

```
pCode = {"T": "Alberta"}
a = input("Enter a 6 character postal code: ")
```

You can get the first character of the post code as `a[0]`

```
print(pCode.get(a[0]))
```